# How to use C# Action with an object?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a generic retry policy that passes in a object and a function to call on that object. I know it's possible with a method but I'm not sure how to include the object.

For example I have an api object that has many different methods that I'd like to pass as the action.  If a certain type of exception occurs I'd need to update values in the api object.

Any ideas?  thanks

```
 public T Do<T>(Api api, Func<T> action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int retryCount = 3)
 {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        for (int retry = 0; retry < retryCount; retry++)
        {
             try
             {
                    return api.action();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `Func<Api, T>` and call it as `action(api)`